# Count field other than id field

Tags: php, mysqli

I have 5 columns in my SQL database
id, name, email, phone, and country
id: total row 54
email total row 45

How I will count how many emails in my database.
I use COUNT function, but not give actual results in case of email.

```
select count(company.email) from company
```

Comment: What is in the `email` field for the remaining 9 rows? Is it `NULL` or empty string?

Comment: First off, there's no php or mysqli here (per the tags you used), just SQL. We need to see the schema and values.

Comment: Voting as unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(company.email) FROM company WHERE company.email IS NOT NULL  AND company.email <> ''
```

This query will exclude the rows that you have no email (either NULL or just empty field)

Answer (score 0):

if email column contains null,

This should work.

```
SELECT COUNT(!ISNULL(email)) FROM company
```

Answer (score 0):

`select count(email) from company where company<>''`

`NULL` will get off the count by themselves